# Unit testing module federated redux toolkit store

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, webpack-module-federation

I created a module federated redux store and inside this store I have a useStore() function which I then call into my other application but when I to test the component using react-testing and jest that calls useStore() I get following error:

```
TypeError: (0 , useStore) is not a function
```

Redux function:

```
export function useStore() {
  const selectD = useAppSelector((state) => state.selectD);
  const selectT= useAppSelector((state) => state.t);
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  return {
    selectD,
    selectT,
    ... more code  
  };
}
```

Inside other app I call it as so:

```
import {  useStore } from "store/store"
function SimpleComponent() {
  // GRAB VARIABLES FROM MWTC-5 REDUX STORE
  const {selectDrawer: {isOpen}, selectTrack} = useStore();
  ... other code 
}
```

The app works great when I run npm run start but the problem is testing the SimpleComponent component that calls useStore();

How would I be able to pass this test?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer for anyone looking to test your redux store and using the same structure as example above, I had to wrap the useStore in a if variable to test if env is in "test" mode.
Ex.

```
function SimpleComponent() {
  let test: any;
  if(!envVars.isTest == true) {
    test = useStore();
  }
)
```

You can then grab the variables or function from test and save them to your useState variables.
so when running my jest test for my SimpleComponent it now ignores that useStore() since it runs in NODE_env = "Test"